# Read rows in CSV differently by various threads in a single Thread Group

Tags: csv, jmeter, threadgroup

I have a test plan with single thread group with 2 http requests.

I want to run a scenario with 10 users. I have a CSV file with 10 values in 4 columns and I want to execute the test plan in the following way:

- First 3 rows, all columns from the CSV file should be used by first 3 users immediately
- Remaining 7 users should take the remaining 7 rows from the same CSV file with use of "single unique value of 4th column of csv file". It should run for 1 hour duration.

How can I run this scenario?

Comment: What "*with use of "single unique value of 4th column of csv file"*" means? Can you provide example of your CSV file data?

Comment: S.NO MobileNO   cookie   IPAddress
1.        xx               10 10.20.30.40
2.     xx               12 10.20.30.41
3.  xx               12 10.20.30.42
4. xx               11 10.20.30.43
5. xx                   9 10.20.30.44
6. xx               11 10.20.30.45
7.     xx                 8 10.20.30.46
8.    xx                8 10.20.30.47
9.  xx                9 10.20.30.48
10. xx               7  10.20.30.49                                          
              remaining 7 users should run with 7 values from csv file but use only one  IPAddress(i.e.10.20.30.43) and run for 1 hour.