# using single csv file for multiple http requests in single thread group

Tags: csv, jmeter

I have a thread group with 2 different HTTP requests to test 10 users with CSV file of 10 rows of data.

In this scenario first HTTP request execute with 3 users with first 3 values from CSV file and remaining 7 users should used by second HTTP request with same CSV file used by remaining 7 data values.

Comment: Didn't you just asked it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140247/read-rows-in-csv-differently-by-various-threads-in-a-single-thread-group ?

Comment: i didn't get the final solution for that. Request to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Switch_Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) with 2 HTTP Samplers under it and use `Switch Value` with changing values: 0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 - it'll execute 3 times first HTTP Sampler and 7 times second HTTP Sampler.

Such switch value can be obtain using JSR223 Sampler or JSR223  Pre Processor (with groovy language) before `Switch_Controller` with the code:

```
vars.put("switchValue", "0001111111".substring( vars.getIteration()-1, vars.getIteration()) );
```

and then use in `Switch Controller` Value: `${switchValue}`

Comment: is both http request executes at a time?

Comment: No. You loop 10 times and the switch is executing 1 at a time

Comment: is both HTTP requests executes at a time?                                            means                                                                                                  
          sampler 1 executes -- (1,2,3) values from csv 
          sampler 2 -- executes from (4,5,6,7 )from csv at a time?

Comment: CSV is loading rows according to iteration, first,second and third rows will be taken by Sampler 1 and the next rows by Sampler 2